# Certificate file not loading in Java Project

Tags: java, properties, certificate

I need to set a property where i am loading a certificate as below -
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/Shashank/cacerts");

Now this works fine if i give the absolute path as above but as i have to generate a runnable jar for this project and share across the team, i can't provide the absolute path. I have created a folder called temp in the project and under that i copied the file and provided like this -
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/temp/cacerts"); but this is not working.

Can someone suggest how to add this correctly so that my jar gets generated properly  with all the details along with this certificate file.

Comment: Can you add it to a resource folder..?

Comment: As a first try, leave out the / before the temp in "/temp/cacerts"
Could you pls show us the line of code when you are accessing the system-property and converting it to a keyStore?

Comment: @GeorgMuehlenberg Hi, I have tried that and it didn't work. The self signed certificate is already imported in the cacerts file of JRE and the same file I have copied to eclipse folder and trying to link it at run time.

When i use the absolute path of my computer it works but not when i use the path from my project in eclipse

Comment: Have you tried using System.getProperty("user.dir");? which will give you the JVM run location (assuming you will deploy the keystore alongside the jar file and run from that directory).  The alternative is to specify the location via a run parameter and control the JVM startup via a top level script.